# Gnome 3.38 doesn't rotates screen automatically

Tags: gnome, screen, display-rotation

Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome 3.36 used to rotate screen automatically when I rotated the device, the new Ubuntu 20.10 with Gnome 3.38 doesn't do it. I've tried with `ctrl+o`to see if the automatic rotation is locked, it isn't. I already have installed and updated `iio-sensor-proxy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that [the bug has been fixed in GNOME 3.38.2](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/3255#note_992094), which looks like it landed in the Ubuntu repositories at the end of December. Has upgrading worked?

You'll also notice in that thread the recommendation of using [ScreenRotator](https://github.com/GuLinux/ScreenRotator/) as a temporary fix.

Comment: I'm not able to say if the upgrade worked since I'm now using KDE Neon, but I'm closing the question since your answer

Answer (score 2):

Not an "answer," but can't comment with my rep:
This seems to be [a bug in GNOME 3.38](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/3255).  Screen rotation stops working even though `iio-sensory-proxy` and `monitor-sensor` indicate all is working properly.  It also appears to distribution agnostic (i.e., it occurs on Ubuntu, Fedora, and Manjaro).

Comment: Thank you, I was scared it could be a problem of the hardware. Is there a way to return to Gnome 3.36? If it is, is it convenient?