# I have Ubuntu 20.10 with Gnome 3.38 but I want to return to Gnome 3.36

Tags: gnome, downgrade, 20.10

I want to return to Gnome 3.36 'cause Gnome 3.38 has given me some problems [link to the problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1290780/gnome-3-38-doesnt-rotates-screen-automatically).

Is it convenient to downgrade Gnome without downgrading Ubuntu, and how can I do it?

Comment: I would recommend asking about the problem that you actually face. Downgrading packages is not a fix and will likely only exacerbate the problem as time goes on. Do you plan to *never* update?  What happens when other software relies on the correct version?... etc... I'm skeptical that your problem has anything to do with differences between v 3.36 and v 3.38.  Correlation does not indicate causation.  We can't advise on your problem because you said nothing about the actual problem you are encountering.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378

Comment: The problem is here [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1290780/gnome-3-38-doesnt-rotates-screen-automatically) It's about gnome 3.38 doesn't rotates screen automatically. In Gnome 3.36 it works so I want to return to that version. I plan to change to DDE when the semester finishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is not advisable to downgrade core packages that many other components rely upon, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138284/how-to-downgrade-a-package-via-apt-get) demonstrates the method to install a specific version of a package, which can be a prior one.

`apt-get install «pkg»=«version»`

That said, the issue you were having appears to have been fixed and made available in GNOME 3.28.2, made available in the repositories at the end of December 2020.