# Downgrade to GNOME 3.36 on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: 20.04, gnome, 21.04

I did an `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` on my *Ubuntu 20.04 LTS* yesterday and so far I like what I'm seeing, but *GNOME 3.38* broke most of my extensions and can't install *GNOME Tweaks*, so, I would like to downgrade to *GNOME 3.36*, anyway how?

Settings say that I'm running *Ubuntu 21.04* with *GNOME 3.38.5*, *Wayland*.

As I can remember, it was running *GNOME 3.36* with *X11*.

*This is originally an Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS with XFCE, but i installed GNOME on it.*

EDIT1: Output of `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`:

```
rose@cryptoazure:~$ ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 300
drwxrwxr-x 75 rose rose 4096 jul 14 15:58 .
drwx------  4 rose rose 4096 jul 16 15:56 ..
drwxrwxrwx  5 root root 4096 jun 11 04:59 appindicatorsupport@rgcjonas.gmail.com
drwxrwxrwx  4 root root 4096 mai 14 23:46 applications-overview-tooltip@RaphaelRochet
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root 4096 mai 17 04:04 app_view_columns@fawtytoo
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4096 jun 11 04:57 bettervolume@tudmotu.com
drwxrwxr-x  3 rose rose 4096 jul  8 10:08 bifocals@shiznatix
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root 4096 jun 11 06:14 big-avatar@gustavoperedo.org
drwxrwxrwx  6 root root 4096 abr 25 02:08 BigSurStatusArea@korpsvart
drwxrwxrwx  4 root root 4096 mai 13 02:28 blur-me@nunchucks
drwxrwxr-x  3 rose rose 4096 jul  2 20:41 blur-my-shell@aunetx
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root 4096 mai  9 00:56 blur-provider@corvettecole.github.com
drwxrwxr-x  5 rose rose 4096 jun 30 11:08 blyr@yozoon.dev.gmail.com
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root 4096 mai 16 01:50 BringOutSubmenuOfPowerOffLogoutButton@pratap.fastmail.fm
drwxrwxr-x  3 rose rose 4096 jul 14 15:58 center-area-horizontal-spacing-fixed@trblwlf.tk
drwxrwxrwx  4 root root 4096 mai 16 01:48 clipboard-indicator@tudmotu.com
drwxrwxr-x  4 rose rose 4096 jul  5 04:31 clock-override@gnomeshell.kryogenix.org
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root 4096 abr 25 02:12 compiz-alike-magic-lamp-effect@hermes83.github.com
drwxrwxrwx  4 root root 4096 mai 10 17:25 CoverflowAltTab@palatis.blogspot.com
drwxrwxrwx  5 root root 4096 mai 28 02:57 custom-hot-corners-extended@G-dH.github.com
drwxrwxrwx  5 root root 4096 mai  2 14:25 dash-to-plank@hardpixel.eu
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4096 jun 29 20:20 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxrwxrwx  4 root root 4096 jun  5 22:23 desktopicons-neo@darkdemon
drwxrwxrwx  5 root root 4096 mai 16 01:49 disconnect-wifi@kgshank.net
drwxrwxrwx  5 root root 4096 abr 25 04:07 dynamic-panel-transparency@rockon999.github.io
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4096 mai 14 23:45 escape-overview@raelgc
drwxrwxr-x  3 rose rose 4096 jul  2 23:28 fildemGMenu@gonza.com
drwxrwxrwx  5 root root 4096 mai 13 02:17 floating-dock@nandoferreira_prof@hotmail.com
drwxrwxrwx  4 root root 4096 abr 26 01:29 GmailMessageTray@shuming0207.gmail.com
drwxrwxr-x  3 rose rose 4096 jun 30 11:08 gnome-visuals-top-bar@evendanan.net
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4096 mai 16 01:44 goodbyegdmflick@pratap.fastmail.fm
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4096 mai 15 00:00 hide-dash-new@gmail.shanmukhateja.com
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4096 mai 14 23:51 hide-dash@xenatt.github.com
drwxrwxrwx  4 root root 4096 mai 27 01:44 hidetopbar@mathieu.bidon.ca
drwxrwxr-x  3 rose rose 4096 jul 14 15:58 icon-area-horizontal-spacing-fixed@trblwlf.tk
drwxrwxrwx  4 root root 4096 mai 25 07:31 icon-hider@kalnitsky.org
drwxrwxrwx  7 root root 4096 jun 30 09:17 just-perfection-desktop@just-perfection
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root 4096 nov  7  2018 lock-keys-osd@n07ftw.github.com
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4096 mai 12 01:05 maximize-to-workspace@raonetwo.github.com
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4096 jun 16 22:50 mbpbat@prithvivishak.gmail.com
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4096 jun 22 17:06 Mock-Universal-Menu@zacharygough
drwxrwxrwx  4 root root 4096 mai 10 17:29 night-light-slider.timur@linux.com
drwxrwxrwx  8 root root 4096 abr 25 03:43 nightthemeswitcher@romainvigier.fr
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4096 mai 17 05:13 no-dash-and-search-in-overview@fthx-freeroot
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4096 abr 25 04:13 notification-position@drugo.dev
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root 4096 abr 25 04:12 notification-timeout@chlumskyvaclav.gmail.com
drwxrwxrwx  4 root root 4096 abr 25 01:51 openweather-extension@jenslody.de
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4096 mai 15 00:00 overview_cleaner@gonza.com
drwxrwxrwx  7 root root 4096 mai 15 00:02 overview-navigation@nathanielsimard.github.com
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4096 mai 15 01:23 powerMenuRemover@CatFace.extension.com
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root 4096 mai 12 00:59 quickmenu@slippinggitty
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4096 mai 15 00:20 refresh-wifi@kgshank.net
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4096 abr 25 04:03 removeaccesibility@lomegor
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4096 mai 17 05:04 remove-alt-tab-delay@daase.net
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4096 abr 25 04:14 remove-dropdown-arrows@mpdeimos.com
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4096 jun 11 04:57 remove-volume-icon@affolter-engineering.ch
drwxrwxrwx  4 root root 4096 mai 14 23:39 scroll-workspaces@gfxmonk.net
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4096 mai 14 22:45 scroll-workspaces-on-void@mason1920.gitlab.io
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4096 jun 11 04:58 scrovol@andyholmes.github.io
drwxrwxrwx  5 root root 4096 mai  9 22:28 shell-configurator@adeswanta
drwxrwxrwx  6 root root 4096 mai 10 17:30 shell-volume-mixer@derhofbauer.at
drwxrwxr-x  2 rose rose 4096 jul  2 22:39 SmallPanelIcon@camporez.com
drwxrwxrwx  7 root root 4096 mai 15 00:16 sound-output-device-chooser@kgshank.net
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root 4096 abr 25 01:52 status-area-horizontal-spacing@mathematical.coffee.gmail.com
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root 4096 abr 25 04:04 trayIconsReloaded@selfmade.pl
drwxrwxrwx  4 root root 4096 mai 16 01:47 tweaks-system-menu@extensions.gnome-shell.fifi.org
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root 4096 jun 29 20:20 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root 4096 jun 29 20:20 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4096 mai 27 02:27 user-pics@comfy
drwxrwxrwx  4 root root 4096 abr 25 01:51 user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4096 abr 25 04:04 wandering-pixel@justinrdonnelly.github.com
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root 4096 abr 25 07:26 windowIsReady_Remover@nunofarruca@gmail.com
drwxrwxrwx  4 root root 4096 mai 14 23:50 windowoverlay-icons@sustmidown.centrum.cz
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root 4096 mai 17 05:06 wintile@nowsci.com
drwxrwxrwx  4 root root 4096 jun 12 09:48 x11gestures@joseexposito.github.io
rose@cryptoazure:~$
```

For `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`

```
rose@cryptoazure:~$ ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 jul 14 22:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 jul 14 22:13 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 jul 14 22:23 ding@rastersoft.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 jul 14 22:13 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 jul 14 22:13 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
rose@cryptoazure:~$
```

EDIT2: Output of `sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool`:

```
rose@cryptoazure:~$ sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
[sudo] password for rose: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-shell-extension-prefs : Depends: gnome-shell (= 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) but 3.38.4-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
                               Depends: gnome-shell-common (= 3.36.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) but 3.38.4-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
rose@cryptoazure:~$
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I have Ubuntu 20.10 with Gnome 3.38 but I want to return to Gnome 3.36](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1291219/i-have-ubuntu-20-10-with-gnome-3-38-but-i-want-to-return-to-gnome-3-36)

Comment: @24601, output gives me some errors, making me unable to neither downgrade or upgrade any further.

Comment: Please correct the heading of your question: Ubuntu version in the heading does not match the version in question body.

Comment: Better to fix your problem with 3.38 than to downgrade. How did 3.38 break your extensions, and what happens when you try to install Tweaks? Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Added outputs of both commands in the post.
And I prefer downgrading, as I'm more used to 3.36
But it's okay if it's not possible tho.

Comment: @AZUREAS Holy sxxt! I've **never** seen a computer with as many gnome-shell extensions as you have. **No wonder that you're having trouble**. First, put 3.38 back on your system. Install Tweaks. **DISABLE ALL** extensions except the ones in /usr. Reboot. Your system should be stable now. Decide which extensions you **MUST** have, and enable them one at a time, noting if problems arise. Then **DELETE** the bulk of your non-necessary extensions.

Comment: @heynnema How should I install Tweaks if an error prompts on?

Comment: @AZUREAS Did you put gnome-shell 3.38 back on yet? Then try to install Tweaks. Otherwise, use the `Extensions` app or go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ to manage extensions.

Comment: @AZUREAS If the above doesn't let you manage extensions, a real quick and dirty way is to temporarily rename the extensions folder and reboot. `mv ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions.HOLD`.

Comment: @heynnema I'm still on 3.38, but I'm unable to install/manage extensions because of that error on my "EDIT2".

Comment: @AZUREAS Have you tried to reinstall gnome-shell and gnome-shell-common? Have you tried renaming the extensions folder as per my last comment?

Comment: Messy system : "This is originally an Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS with XFCE, but i installed GNOME on it.", 30 extensions .... Time for a fresh reinstall. Will cost you less time. Alternatively, remove all components, then download source code and compile. That is also a way to build your custom system.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: @vanadium I decided I'll do a fresh install again, I still will use Ubuntu Studio because I make music & I need some features Ubuntu Studio has, but I'll be more careful with extensions and random upgrade commands, but still, I'll leave this issue open in case someone needs help with a similar problem.

Comment: @heynnema Tried both, re-installing gnome-shell broke even some more things, like some apps just vanishing and/or being unusable...I think it's time for a fresh install again.

Comment: @vanadium Oh and by the way, I'll use normal Ubuntu 20.04, but I'll use [Ubuntu Studio Installer](https://ubuntustudio.org/ubuntu-studio-installer) on it.

Comment: @AZUREAS Yes, start from scratch. Fresh reinstall. DON'T install so many gnome-shell extensions... only 5-6 extensions max please.